# Java ForkJoinPool not doing what I expect

Tags: java, multithreading, join, fork, pool

I am just learning about Java's ForkJoinPool. I created a little example for myself in order to obtain a better level of comprehension. I expect the code I wrote to produce some output, but I see nothing in the console window. There are no errors, so I may be misunderstanding how to use this service. Please ignore method names that do not appear to accurately describe what the method is doing. This is scratch code after all.

```
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

public class SortTask extends RecursiveAction {
    final int THRESHOLD = 10;
    int[] array;
    int begin, end;

    public SortTask(int[] array, int begin, int end) {
        this.array = array;
        this.begin = begin;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if((end - begin) < THRESHOLD) {
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
                array[i] = i;
            }
        } else {
            int middle = (end - begin) / 2;
            invokeAll(new SortTask(array, begin, middle), new SortTask(array, begin, middle));
            merge(array, begin, end);
        }
    }

    public void merge(int[] array, int begin, int end) {
        System.out.println(array.length);
    }
}
```

Also:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
            int[] list = new int[1000];
            SortTask st = new SortTask(list, 0, 999);
            ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
            pool.execute(st);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pretty sure you want `middle, end` for the second part of this: `invokeAll(new SortTask(array, begin, middle), new SortTask(array, begin, middle));`

Comment: Probably want `int i=begin; i<end;` here too: `for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {`.  Otherwise you are splitting the task into bite size chunks and doing the entire array instead of the small piece.

Comment: Use 1000 for `end` instead of 999.  Or start the second task with `(array, middle+1, end)` and use `i <=end` in your loops.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java program is exiting before the ForkJoin task really starts going.  You need to "wait" for the task to complete, after starting it, by using `invoke` instead of `execute`.

```
pool.invoke(st);
```